# C# generics: How to specify type constraint and return instance of generic type

Tags: java, c#, generics

**In java** I can make a method with the following signature:

```
public <E extends Form> E makeForm(Class<E> formType) {
    //return new instance of formType
}
```

You pass a class to the method that is constrained, and return an instance of that generic type. This way you can do things like:

```
makeForm(SomeForm.class).specificSomeFormMethod();
```

How can I do this **in C#**? From what I've found so far it's not possible? 
I can make the generic type for the form instance OR for the type parameter, but not for both, and I also don't know how to constrain a Type parameter to be only of a specific class.

I'm not quite sure how to label this, so that might be my issue as well. Perhaps I'm overthinking it? I need another person's view!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean you want generic type constraints:

```
public E MakeForm<E>() where E : Form { }
```

The `where` indicates the start of the type constraints. Here it says that `E` should be or derive from `Form`.

You call it like this:

```
MyFormType form = MakeForm<MyFormType>();
```

---

When you just have the type, and nothing more, you can use this:

```
public Form MakeForm(Type formType)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(formType) as Form;
}

Form form = MakeForm(typeof(MyFormType));
```

Comment: Hello, yes, this works! But I can't always use `MakeForm<E>();`. Sometimes I have to call it with `MakeForm(someType);` while enforcing that someType can only be a Form type during compile time. Is it still possible to enforce it that way?

Comment: Updated, make sure to test for `null` in the second method.

Comment: Thanks! I assume C# does not have something like `Class<E>` for parameters?

Comment: No, it doesn't. (It wouldn't make sense to me if it had since it would be very hard to check when passing parameters around).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [new() type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) which allows calls to the generic type's default constructor.

```
public class MakeForm<E> where E : FormType, new()
{
    // Method which returns a new E
    public E MakeForm()
    {
        return new E();   // this works because of the new() constraint
    }
}
```